# C# Looking for pattern ideas - Inheritance w/ constructor issue

Tags: c#, design-patterns, entity-framework-4

I have a multiple layered application I'm rewriting using Entity Framework 4 w/ Code First. The important things:

In the data layer, on my context, I have:

```
public DbSet<MobileSerialContainer> Mobiles { get; set; }
```

This context has a static instance. I know, I know, terrible practice. There are reasons which aren't relevant to this post as to why I'm doing this.

MobileSerialContainer consists of the following:

```
[Table("Mobiles")]
public sealed class MobileSerialContainer
{
    [Key]
    public long Serial { get; set; }

    [StringLength(32)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MobileSerialContainer() { }

    public MobileSerialContainer(Mobile mobile)
    {
        Mobile = mobile;
        LeContext.Instance.Mobiles.Add(this);
    }

    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string FullClassName
    {
        get { return Mobile == null ? "" : Mobile.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName; }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value == FullClassName)
                return;

            Mobile = null;

            var type = Type.GetType(value);
            if (type == null)
                return;

            if (!type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Mobile))
                && type != typeof(Mobile))
                return;

            var constructor = type.GetConstructor(new [] { GetType() });

            // The problem here is that Person ( which extends mobile ) does not have a constructor that takes a MobileSerialContainer.
            // This is a problem of course, because I want to make this entire layer transparent to the system, so that each derivative
            // of Mobile does not have to implement this second constructor. Blasphemy!

            if (constructor == null)
                return;

            Mobile = (Mobile)constructor.Invoke(new object[] { this });
        }
    }

    public string SerializedString
    {
        get
        {
            return Mobile == null ? "" : Mobile.Serialize();
        }
        set
        {
            if (Mobile == null)
                return;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                return;

            Mobile.Deserialize(value);
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public Mobile Mobile { get; set; }

    public void Delete()
    {
        LeContext.Instance.Mobiles.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

Now... I know this is a long post bear with me. Mobile is this:

```
public class Mobile
{
    public long Serial { get { return Container.Serial; } }

    public string Name { get { return Container.Name; } set { Container.Name = value; } }

    public Mobile()
    {
        Container = new MobileSerialContainer(this);
    }

    public Mobile(MobileSerialContainer container)
    {
        Container = container;
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        Container.Delete();
    }

    private MobileSerialContainer Container { get; set; }

    protected static string MakeSafeString(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return value;

        return value.Replace("&", "&amp;")
                    .Replace(",", "&comma;")
                    .Replace("=", "&eq;");
    }

    protected static string MakeUnsafeString(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return value;

        return value.Replace("&eq;", "=")
                    .Replace("&comma;", ",")
                    .Replace("&amp;", "&");
    }

    public virtual string Serialize()
    {
        string result = "";

        var properties = PersistentProperties;

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            string name = MakeSafeString(property.Name);
            var value = property.GetValue(this, null);
            string unsafeValueString = (string)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(string));
            string valueString = MakeSafeString(unsafeValueString);
            result += name + "=" + valueString + ",";
        }

        return result;
    }

    public virtual void Deserialize(string serialized)
    {
        var properties = PersistentProperties.ToList();
        var entries = serialized.Split(',');
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry))
                continue;

            var keyPair = entry.Split('=');
            if (keyPair.Length != 2)
                continue;

            string name = MakeUnsafeString(keyPair[0]);
            string value = MakeUnsafeString(keyPair[1]);

            var property = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == name);
            if (property == null)
                continue;

            object rawValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, property.PropertyType);
            property.SetValue(this, rawValue, null);
        }
    }

    protected IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> PersistentProperties
    {
        get
        {
            var type = GetType();
            var properties = type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PersistAttribute), true).Any());

            return properties;
        }
    }
}
```

Several layers above this, I have the System layer, in which I have the class Person:

```
public class Person : Mobile
{
    [Persist]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The basic idea is this: I want the System layer to have almost no knowledge of the Data layer. It creates anything that extends "Mobile", which is automatically saved to the database. I don't want to have a table for Person, hence the weird serialization stuff, because there are literally hundreds of classes that extend Mobile. I don't want hundreds of tables. All of this serialization stuff works perfectly, the SerializedString bit, saving everything, reloading, etc etc. The only thing I haven't come up with a solution for is:

I don't want to have to implement the two constructors to Person:

```
public Person() : base() { }

public Person(MobileSerialContainer container)
    : base(container) { }
```

as that requires the System layer to have more knowledge of the Data layer.

The weird serialization string thing stays. The reflection business stays. I know it's slow, but database writes and reads are very rare, and asynchronous anyway.

Besides that, I'm looking for any cool ideas about how to resolve this. Thanks!

[edit]
Changed a miswritten line of code in the MobileSerialContainer class pasted here.

Comment: You want Person to have a Mobile, not be a mobile. Get rid of the inheritance.

Comment: Is this a web site?  If so, static data context is not just bad practice, it's broken practice, since statics are shared between all users of the site, which means it will have concurrency issues and probably result in random data corruption and crashing.  If it's a stand-alone app with only one user, then it's just bad practice.

Comment: Mystere Man - This is not a website. I'm actually relying on everything being attached to the same context so that every so often I can do a SaveChanges() ( of sorts... ) and basically flush everything to the database all at once.

Comment: Tony Hopkinson - This may become a problem if I need to extend Person to Employee, then Employee to Manager and Employee also to CFO and so forth. Employee may have a property like HourlyRate; Manager may have a property like

Comment: ( cont.. accidentally hit enter ) "int ManagedEmployeeCount", but still needs the HourlyRate property, etc..

Comment: HourlyRate, MonthlySalary, tomato tomahto..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are rewriting your application, you could reconsider all the design of your system to keep your domain layer (System layer) independent from your Data Access layer using :

- A repository pattern to handle access to your database (dataContext)
- A domain layer for your business objects (mobile and stuff)
- Inversion Of Control pattern (IOC) to keep your layers loosely coupled

The inheritance stuff is definitively not the good way to go to keep a system loosely coupled.

Comment: To be more specific, I have a domain layer that houses all of the entities except for the few that I've decided to give access to the context, then the Data layer on top of that ( with Mobile and MobileSerialContainer ), on top of that I have a Server layer which is home to a bunch of sockets logic / networking stuff, plus an imperial ton of events. The System layer is on top of that. The Server layer is only aware of the System layer to the extent that it loads the compiled assembly ( Assembly.LoadFrom( "etc.System.dll" ) and then uses reflection to run any static Initialize() functions.

Comment: I was considering using repositories but I didn't really see a benefit to doing so as I'm fairly content allowing the Server layer access and knowledge of the context.

Comment: Inversion of Control was another thing I did think about, I can't quite remember off hand why I decided not to implement it. However, I'll do some more mulling over of your suggestions for using IOC and repositories. You've given me some things to think about for now, thanks!

Comment: As an aside, I'm not concerned about the speed of loading from / adding to the database, nor the speed of loading the System layer as these things happen rarely. Instantiating classes, however, is a process that needs to happen very rapidly and so I think this is why I've been working this implementation so far without Windsor or the like. Do you have a better recommendation for implementing an inversion of control pattern? I'm not closed off to the idea if it can be done with very little overhead.

Comment: I think that's legit to ask and I would recommend you to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548077/what-performance-overhead-do-ioc-containers-involve which speaks about performance with IOC ! By the way, you seem using a lot of reflection ... which you know is pretty expensive too ;)

Comment: I'm going to be doing massive amounts of research and restructuring next week when I have a chance to get back into the project. Looks like this may turn out to be exactly the answer I need, thanks! I'll mark it as the solution if this works out well.

Comment: I'm still figuring out though, how to map properties on derived classes from Mobile. Say I have 100 classes that derive from Mobile with unique properties, I don't want to have to write a repository for each one. I also don't want to add 100 tables to my database... which is originally why I was using reflection, though my brain is now whirring about serialization. Do you have any suggestions for this? Basically I'm looking to write everything to the Mobiles table at this point. This decision directly affects my next design move.

Comment: Repository doesn't mean that your entities are saved in database; they can be serialized, saved in database or whatever you want. It's up to your repository implementation, which can be generic (IRepository<Mobile>). For the 100 tables, you have different strategy to implement inheritance with EF : TPH, TPC ... Choose the best for your project !

Comment: I've implemented a repo pattern, as well as moved data-layer entities down with their brothers n sisters in the domain layer. I wound up accomplishing "serialization" by adding a key-value property table that includes a FK constraint to the Mobiles table. The code up in the System layer uses another class which houses Mobile, let's call "Moo", and includes a ["key"] operator to access values from the property table. This way, anything that extends from Moo can include getters / setters like so: set { self["taco"] = value; }

Comment: I'm not actually working on this right now, so that's all off the top of my head, but i suppose I could give more detail this upcoming weekend in case anyone is interested in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `type.GetConstructors()` not `type.GetConstructor()`, this will let you get the base constructors and pass the type you are looking for.

Comment: I did actually try that already, it does not yield the base constructors :(

Comment: Otherwise this would have been perfect :)